# excute intellij cucumber scenario from outside intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

I have running intellij with cucumber scenarios.
Now I want to start a specific scenario from outside intellij.

Is there a possibility e.g. from a shell or a java programm to excecute something in intellij?
Is there a possibility to use a currently running intellij instance for that?

Thanks
Jochen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not provide many info, but I bet if you use Maven you can run from a terminal / git bash etc your tests outside IDE, e.g.:

mvn test
See more info here: [Run Cucucmber from terminal](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/run-cucumber-test-from-command-line-terminal/)

Comment: I use maven in my project and your link is very helpful and I will try. My first idea was, to use the currently running intellj to save resources and avoid maven reload it all. So I thought how to trigger maven or cucumber to run a test inside the already running intellij